# Web Scrape your own Stack Overflow profile using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am currently experimenting with web scraping my own Stack Overflow [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14282714/quinten) (logout) using `rvest`. To find the CSS tags I use the [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=nl) extension for google chrome. To start I would like to extract the numbers with headers under the **Stats** header of my profile which are marked as green and yellow (colors because of using the extension to find tag) in the picture below:

[image]

This gives me the following CSS tags: `.md\:fl-auto , .fc-dark`. The `.fc-dark` tag is for the numbers and `.md\:fl-auto` for the headers (reputation, reached, etc.). Extracting the numbers works, but extracting the headers, I get the following error: `Error: '\:' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".md\:"`. Is it possible to extract this CSS tag and save both outputs in a dataframe? Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://stackoverflow.com/users/14282714/quinten"
profile <- read_html(link)

numbers <- profile %>% html_nodes(".fc-dark") %>% html_text()
numbers
[1] "12,688" "49k"    "847"    "9"     
headers <- profile %>% html_nodes(".md\:fl-auto") %>% html_text()
Error: '\:' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".md\:"
```

I am open to better options for web scraping my StackOverflow profile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
profile %>% html_nodes(".md\\:fl-auto") %>% html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_squish() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  tidyr::separate(value, into = c("number", "header"), sep = "\\s") %>% 
  mutate(number = stringr::str_remove(number, "\\,") %>% 
           sub("k", "000", ., fixed = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  number header    
   <dbl> <chr>     
1  12688 reputation
2  49000 reached   
3    847 answers   
4     10 questions
```

Comment: Simply escaping special characters in this way didn't work in my case (the special character was ! but I'm not sure why it should make a difference)